# Connection String vs Data Service call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, odata, azure-sql-database

I have 2 separate MVC 3 websites (A & B), both with their own SQL Azure databases which may or may not be on the same server. Both are using Code First Entity Framework and will be deployed to windows azure.

Website A is considered the master website and database. This holds data of the clients using our software along with usernames and passwords. I want website B to connect to website A's database when user logs in or registers. Website B will also need to hit website A's database in order to get some of the client's data after the user is logged in.

Right now I just have this one website B hitting website A's database, but in the future I will have more of these websites like website B hitting the main database for the same reasons.

My question is what is the best way to send and receive data between these smaller websites and the master database?

At first I was just using 2 connection strings in website B with two different contexts(one for each db). I liked this because the object types all flowed together, there wasn't any converting to do.However, I wasn't sure if this was the best and most secure way to go.

Another option I have been looking at is oData Services. I do like the idea of having everything separated and just calling the service when needing data from the master database. The issue I am having though is transferring the data from the service into my model's objects. I am having to do nasty things like this foreach statement:

```
public ActionResult GetMovies()
    {
        var ctx = new MovieODataService.MovieContext(new Uri("http://localhost:54274/MovieService.svc/"));

        DataServiceQuery<MovieODataService.Movie> query = ctx.Movies;

        var response = query.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<MovieODataService.Movie>;

        var model = new MovieModel();

        model.Movies = new List<Movie>();

        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            model.Movies.Add(new Movie
                                 {
                                     Title = item.Title,
                                     ReleaseDate = item.ReleaseDate
                                 });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I am also open to any other suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OData is great for a lot of things, but where it really shines is in exposing rich queryability over (preferably) schematized information. That doesn't really feel like a great fit for authentication calls.

Have you looked at the more traditional authentication protocols, such as [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)? That seems like a much better fit for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have not looked into that, but I will. Thanks for the reply!